# How to fix "'int' object is not subscriptable" error in Python's vk_api

Tags: python, api, vk

I don't know how to fix below error:

```
   first_name = opread["profiles"][i]["first_name"]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

To give you some context this is my code:

```
opread = vk.method("messages.getConversationMembers",{"peer_id":id})
count = opread["count"]
for i in range(count):
    first_name = opread["profiles"][i]["first_name"]
    last_name = opread["profiles"][i]["last_name"]
    peer_id = opread["profiles"][i]["id"]
```

Comment: check `print( opread["profiles"], type(opread["profiles"]) )` and later `print( opread["profiles"][i], type(opread["profiles"][i]) )` - maybe you get integer value instead of list/dictionary and then you try someting like `7[i]` or `7["first_name"]`

Comment: Yes, I get 2 identical profiles

Comment: did you get number and type `int` ? This `int` makes problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if VK sends a duplicate profile (as you stated in your comment). In any case you would have best results if you run the range function over the profiles list instead of the count variable:

```
opread = vk.method("messages.getConversationMembers",{"peer_id":id})
for i in range(len(opread["profiles"])):
    first_name = opread["profiles"][i]["first_name"]
    last_name = opread["profiles"][i]["last_name"]
    peer_id = opread["profiles"][i]["id"]
```

If you don't need to hold a reference to the index you even could do it like:

```
opread = vk.method("messages.getConversationMembers",{"peer_id":id})
for i in opread["profiles"]:
    first_name = i["first_name"]
    last_name = i["last_name"]
    peer_id = i["id"]
```